# Nativescript application running on background automatically open in foreground

Tags: android, ios, background, nativescript, foreground

I have a nativescritp app, which receive phone calls.
When the app is not running on foreground, it still receives the calls, which is fine.
What I need to do is to "load" / "run" / "show" the application on the screen, so the user can answer the phone call or decline it.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be quite straight forward as building an app and there are no ready made plugins available to achieve this.

For iOS you will have to implement [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit?language=objc) and for Android you will have follow the set of procedures explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged).

FYI, with iOS your normal code won't run any longer if app is minimised. With Android you will have to implement the `android.telecom.ConnectionService` as explained in the link above, refer `onShowIncomingCallUi()` for showcasing UI for the call.

If you are not proficient with marshalling native code ([iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) & [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js)) then I would suggest you to start there.